# UITableView Expandable + Dynamic cell height (According to the UITextView inside UITableViewCell)

Tags: uitableview, expandablelistview

I am working on a project where I have to implement same as news application. I mean initially all cells will contain News Title and when user clicks on any title then the content will display by expanding the cell. Please suggest some tutorials for this. I am using following code for expansion of cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isChild =
    currentExpandedIndex > -1
    && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
    && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    if (isChild) {
        NSLog(@"A child was tapped, do what you will with it");
        return;
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if (currentExpandedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        currentExpandedIndex = -1;
    }
    else {

        BOOL shouldCollapse = currentExpandedIndex > -1;

        if (shouldCollapse) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
        }

        currentExpandedIndex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex) ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count] : indexPath.row;

        [self expandItemAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few which is very good to implement expendable cell :

1. https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView
2. https://github.com/singhson/Expandable-Collapsable-TableView

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Set expanded cell then tell tableView to redraw with animation
    self.expandedRow = indexPath;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandedRow]) {
      return EXPANDED_HEIGHT;
   }

    return NORMAL_HEIGHT;
}
```