# How to fix jumping cells in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift

There is one problem, I can not solve, namely - I fight with a smooth animation of adding new cells to the table (tableView.insertRows). The video below shows how at the opening all the cells are wildly jerking, I encode the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (destinationData?[indexPath.row]) != nil {
        return 110
    } else {
        return 95
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (destinationData?[indexPath.row]) != nil {
        if(indexPath.row + 1 >= (destinationData?.count)!) {
            expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
        }
        else {
            if(destinationData?[indexPath.row+1] != nil) {
                expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
                // Close Cell (remove ExpansionCells)
            } else {
                contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        for i in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0)] , with: .bottom)
        }
    }
}

private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        for _ in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.remove(at: index + 1)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

[VIDEO](https://yadi.sk/i/sgmVtjpD3Zadbc)

Comment: You are inserting table rows and deleting table rows on click? This isn't the best way to achieve what you want.
You can choose to try other ways like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740263/uitableview-expandable-dynamic-cell-height-according-to-the-uitextview-inside

Comment: My 2 cent: I usually prefer to create cells with a tableview inside that give at the cell the height of the open cell

Comment: are you using estimatedRowsHeight for dynamic rows height?

Comment: Try calling insertRows/deleteRows between `TableView.beginUpdates()` & `TableView.endUpdates()` methods.

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko, no, i use static height rows cell

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin so simply use second point from my answer, it should help

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko this does not work

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Usually `UITableView` start jumping when it can't easily estimate correct height for cell.

To fix that, first return correct height in `tableView(_, estimatedHeightForRowAt: ) -> CGFloat` method

Second point, you can store current `contentOffset`

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**UPDATE**

So if you are need to insert and delete couple of indexes, you need to perform this operation in single `beginUpdates()endUpdates()` block

Try to change your code to this:

```
if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
    var indexes: [IndexPath] = []
    for i in 1...infoMain.count {
        destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
        indexes.append(IndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0))
    }
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexes, with: .bottom)
    self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
    for _ in 1...infoMain.count {
        destinationData?.remove(at: index + 1)
        indexes.append(IndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0))
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexes, with: .top)
    self.tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Crash, 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: this is my mistake in removing the cell, I will fix it and try your method

Comment: I was helped by the way to delete and add all cells at once, rather than one at a time. The answer is indicated below. I think it's the easiest way was?

Comment: Yes, if it's helped you, than it's a better answer I guess. My point was that you need to calculate cell height and keep your tableView `contentOffset`

Comment: I hurried and the method with the grouping of objects and adding them immediately does not solve the problem

Comment: By the way, I noticed that the problem manifests itself only on the iPhone 5s, se.

Answer (score 1):

If you do multiple animated changes to tableview content you should wrap them all to `tableView.beginUpdates() ... tableView.endUpdates()` calls.
You are doing multiple insertion or deletion in `for...in` loop.
Change your code to this:

```
private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0)] , with: .bottom)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for _ in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.remove(at: index + 1)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Even better approach is to accumulate `IndexPath`'s you want to change into array and perform all insertions or deletions at once:

```
private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        var indexesToInsert = [IndexPath]()
        for i in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
            indexesToInsert.append(IndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0))
        }
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexesToInsert, with: .bottom)
    }
}

private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    if let infoMain = destinationData?[index]?.infoMain {
        var indexesToDelete = [IndexPath]()
        for _ in 1...infoMain.count {
            destinationData?.remove(at: index + 1)
            indexesToDelete.append(IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0))
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexesToDelete, with: .top)
    }
}
```